# Language pack service pack

Tags: service-pack, language-pack

I don't quite understand "Language pack service pack". My environment is running with SP2013 standard with simplified and traditional Chinese language pack installed.

When I try to download the SP for language pack:
http://www.microsoft.com/zh-tw/download/details.aspx?id=42004

I found it also have different language version. So I need to download all 3 language packs (Engish, and two Chinese) sp and install them on all server instance in the farm?

Comment: Yes you do have to do that for the SP:s

Comment: Has this changed since 2010? Myth number 2? http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/install-sharepoint-2010-service-pack-2-the-right-way.html

Comment: Myth #2 actually describe what Robert just mentioned.

Comment: You asked if you need to download all 3 language packs, and got the answer yes. The myth claims that you don't need to download the language pack for the default installed language which make's it 2 language packs, just like Waqas mentions. :)

Comment: Ya.. I hate Microsoft always make the naming so lame. The service pack's language pack's patching service pack blahblahblah =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to services pack for each installed language packs...as you said you have 3 different languages then you need to download all 3 and install them on all servers in the farm.

Also check this Technet, same applicable to LPs:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108(v=office.14).aspx#section4

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I run the English language pack service pack exe it said no product is affacted by this pack. I think it is included in the SP1. But I still need to run the other two.

Comment: Yes, if your default language is English. You need other 2s.